# YouTube channel activated monetization

Tags: youtube, google-adsense

In this screenshot:

[image: screensho]

why does Monetization show "You're almost done!" ?

I seems bind everything correct I mean about binding YouTube and AdSense.

What do I need to do to activate my AdSense?

Comment: It says it right there... All you have to do is wait.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you already linked it and you just now need to wait.

[This YouTube support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72866?ref_topic=6029973) has more info just in case.

Scroll down a bit, open the item *If you already have an approved AdSense account* and select **AdSense association** link from the text.